# Determining C executable name

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, executable, linkage

When we are compiling a C program the output is stored in a.out. How can we redirect the compiled output to another file?

Comment: gcc source.c -o name

Answer (score 60):

Most C compilers provide an option for this, such as the `-o` option for `gcc` and some others:

```
gcc -o gentext gentext.c
cc  -o mainprog -Llib -lmymath firstbit.c secondbit.o
xlc -o coredump coredump.c
```

Answer (score 25):

`-ofilename` will make `filename` instead of `a.out`.

Answer (score 14):

According to the manual:

```
-o <file>  Place the output into <file>
```

Answer (score 9):

In Unix, where C originated from, C programs are usually compiled module-by-module, and then the compiled modules are linked into an executable. For a project that consists of modules `foo.c` and `bar.c`, the commands would be like this:

```
cc -c foo.c
cc -c bar.c
cc -o myprog foo.o bar.o
```

(With -c, the output filename becomes the source file with the suffix replaced with .o.)

This allows you to also re-compile only those modules that have changed, which can be a big time saver for big programs, but can also become pretty tricky. (This part is usually automated using `make`.)

For a single-module program there's not really any point in first compiling to a .o file, and then linking, so a single command suffices:

```
cc -o foo foo.c
```

For single-module programs, it is customary to call the resulting executable program the same as the C source file without the .c suffix. For multi-module programs, there is no hard custom on whether the output is named after the file with the main function or not, so you're free to invent whatever strikes your fancy.

Answer (score 6):

With the `-o` option.

```
gcc main.c -o myCoolExecutable.o
```

This is ok if your program consists of a single file. If you have more files I suggest using `make`: create a `Makefile` and then run the command `make`.

A `Makefile` is a file containing some rules for compilation.
An example can be the following (`#` means the line is a comment):

```
CXX = gcc

#CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11
#INC_PATH = ...
#LIBS = ...

SOURCEDIR := yourSourceFolder
SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SOURCEDIR)/*.c)
OBJDIR=$(SOURCEDIR)/obj

OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(SOURCES))
DEPENDS := $(patsubst $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.d, $(SOURCES))

# ADD MORE WARNINGS!
WARNING := -Wall -Wextra

# .PHONY means these rules get executed even if
# files of those names exist.
.PHONY: all clean

# The first rule is the default, ie. "make",
# "make all" and "make parking" mean the same
all: yourExecutableName

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJECTS) $(DEPENDS) yourExecutableName

# Linking the executable from the object files
# $^   # "src.c src.h" (all prerequisites)
yourExecutableName: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(WARNING) $^ -o $@
    #$(CXX) $(WARNING) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INC_PATH) $^ -o $@ $(LIBS)

-include $(DEPENDS)

$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c Makefile | $(OBJDIR)
    $(CXX) $(WARNING) -MMD -MP -c $< -o $@
```

Shortly `CXX` variable defines your compiler (gcc, g++), `with CXXFLAGS` you can define flags for your compilation (i.e. `-std=c++11`). Then you can include and define custom (`INC_PATH` and `LIBS`: not set in the example). With `SOURCEDIR` you can specify your source code directory (where `*.c` files are).Then `SOURCES` is basically telling that the source files for the compilation are all the files having extension `*.c`.

The `Makefile` contains a set of rules whose structure is the following:

```
output: inputs
    commandToExecute
```

The rule to generate your executable file is

```
yourExecutableName: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(WARNING) $^ -o $@
```

which is equivalent to `gcc -Wall -Wextra $(OBJECTS) -o yourExecutableName`.

`$(OBJECTS)` are the object file resulting from the compilation. When the above rule is executed, if they are not found make will continue scanning the file to find a rule to generate them. In this case the rule to generate these files is:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c Makefile | $(OBJDIR)
    $(CXX) $(WARNING) -MMD -MP -c $< -o $@
```

If further information is needed let me know.

Comment: Best answer by far, `make` is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

If `foo` will be your executable and `bar.c` is your source file then the command is:

```
gcc -o foo bar.c
```

Answer (score 2):

```
gcc filename.c -o outputfile
```

This command will directly create an `outputfile.exe` OR `outputfile.out` according to operating system. In place of `filename.c` OR `outputfile` we can enter path, as shown below.

```
gcc ./home/user/filename.c -o ./home/outputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

Compile using:

```
cc -o <opfilename> <filename.c>
```

Execute using:

```
./<opfilename>
```

Answer (score 0):

**The format of giving the Name of .exe file according to the User Choice in C Language**

****step 1** :-** Run the gcc (or the compiler you have) in the below format on the Terminal

```
    gcc -o put_your_name_you_want_to_give (space) your_file_name_you_want_to_execute
```

NB:- If you are Running **"Vs Code"** Use the 'Tab' key for the Auto completion.

****step 2** :-** Write down the name of the program in format

```
           .\the_name_you_have_given.exe
```

you are done!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are in ubuntu

**step-1:** run gcc with these commands to compile `filename.c`

`gcc filename.c -o filename.out`

- `filename.out` will be created, (it might or  might not be shown where the other files are stored)

**step-2:** execute the `filename.out` by

`./filename.out`

**step-3**: wait for the output

thats it ,  you are done