# How to compile a C program with gcc?

Tags: c, gcc

I wrote a simple program named b.c to call `dir` in Windows 10 cmd via C.

This is what the script looks like:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    system("dir");
    return 0;
}
```

I typed this in cmd

```
gcc b.c
b
```

but it returns

```
J:\fundamental of C programming>b
'b' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

This is how I add path

[image]

I don't think it is path matter.

So how can I fix it?

Comment: Do dir in your current directory and find if there's any new executable created. By default, gcc will generate an executable like a.out or a.exe (in windows, but I am not so sure).

Comment: Yes. Now I understand. I didn't specify the output file. mingw produces a.exe by default. But I run b instead.

Comment: The problem is that you can't find the executable to run — not that when the executable is run it cannot find `dir` to run.

Comment: "Fundamental of C Programming" *starts* with `system`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to run

```
gcc b.c -o b.exe
```

Without `-o` option it'll use the default output executable name which is `a.exe` on Windows and [`a.out` on *nix systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.out). You can easily see the a.exe with the `dir` command

> `-o file`
>
> - Place output in file file. This applies to whatever sort of output is being produced, whether it be an executable file, an object file, an assembler file or preprocessed C code.
> - If `-o` is not specified, the default is to put an executable file in `a.out`, the object file for source.suffix in `source.o`, its assembler file in `source.s`, a precompiled header file in `source.suffix.gch`, and all preprocessed C source on standard output.
>
> https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html

For more information read [Determining C executable name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/653807/995714)

Of course you can also run `a` instead of `b`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. But I don't understand why it produces an a.exe under  current directory instead of b.exe

Comment: @Gang mingw produces a.exe on windows, if you are using it

Comment: @Gang the default output filename for gcc is `a` plus an extension regardless of the source file name

Answer (score 0):

Compile like this

```
gcc -o b b.c
```

by specifying output filename

```
-o <output_file>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to update bin path variable in windows 
open next link to see how:
http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/run-c-program-command-prompt-windows/